# search function in pdf not working on url

Tags: url, pdf, adobe

i am trying to open pdf file with #search function in chrome, but it is not working.

google chrome version Version 43.0.2357.124

Example
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#search=%22word%22

tried also
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#search="word"

it just open the file but there are no words highlighted
can someone please explain why it is not working? thanks

p.s. other functions like #page=3 are working

Comment: asking after 6 years. did you find anything useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your adobe plugin extension for chrome.
[chrome adobe extension](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/12/get-reader-or-acrobat-to-work-in-chrome-compact-pdf-output-from-chrome/)

Comment: if u satisfied for answer .plz marks answer as useful.